# Changing different divs to background image jQuery Fade

Tags: jquery, background-image, fadein, fadeout

I am slightly an amateur at jQuery but have managed to come up with four divs that fade in and out across each other. Although this works okay, I would like to replace the current four divs with only one div and fade in different background images for that div instead of fading four divs.

So I fade four background images in one div instead of fading four separate divs.

The current code I have now:

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fade($ele) {
        $ele.fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            var $next = $(this).next('.HomeImage');
            fade($next.length > 0 ? $next : $(this).parent().children().first());
       });
    };  

    fade($('div#stretchParent > .HomeImage').first());
}); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="stretchParent"><!-- Stretch -->
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
</div><!-- End of Stretch -->
```

So the desired HTML I wish to use with four fading divs is:

```
<div id="stretchParent"><!-- Stretch -->
    <div class="HomeImage"></div>
</div><!-- End of Stretch -->
```

Any idea or help as I am completely stumped and it was me and a friend who wrote the jQuery.

Thanks in advance to any direction, links or help.

Comment: Create a JSfiddle with you code. And ihave a look

Comment: @DavidAllen - Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owenoneill/Wzcgn/8/

Comment: Ive edited my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK give this a go http://jsfiddle.net/davidja/Wzcgn/11/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $backgroundimages = ['blue', 'red', 'grey', 'black'];
    var $backgroundcount = 0;

    function fade($ele) {
        $ele.css('background-color', $backgroundimages[$backgroundcount]);
        $backgroundcount++;
        $ele.fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            if ($backgroundcount >= $backgroundimages.length) {
                $backgroundcount = 0;
            };
            fade($ele);
        });
    };

    fade($('#stretchParent  .HomeImage').first());
});
```

To use images instead its something like below (untested);

```
var $backgroundimages = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg'];

$ele.css('background-image', 'url('+$backgroundimages[$backgroundcount]+')');
```

Comment: Basically when you use Var you make the variable global which means you can access it within a function.  you can pass an array with the list of colors and which color should be next.

Comment: I want to do it with background images, not colours, sorry I just used colours as an example..

Comment: I change my original code to colors.  But i have made a edit.

Comment: Thank you @David Allen! Perfect and learn't a little bit about arrays, so thank you! much appreciated.

Comment: NP.  I still get stuck on Global variables at times :D